# audio problem with SDR on MacOS

Tags: software-defined-radio, hackrf, macos

I'm experimenting with SDR on MacOS High Sierra. Trying both CubeSDR and GQRX and experiencing similar issues with both. The applications seem to work, but the audio is choppy and chipmunk-like. Obviously a problem with buffering and sample-rate conversion. Both apps use SoapySDR.

I'm currently using a HackRF device, but will test with a stock RTL-SDR device and try and isolate the problem further.

If anyone has any ideas as to how to resolve this, I would be grateful.

update: the chipmunking has been solved by rolling back the HackRF firmware to API version 1.02 from API version 1.03. Audio is still choppy after a few seconds though. suspecting a hackrf library issue.

Comment: What audio rate do you set in your software? Try 44.1 kHz or 48 kHz. Also, make sure you set a SDR sampling rate the SDR device actually supports – your problem would also be symptomatic for e.g. setting 48 kHz audio rate and 4.8 MHz SDR rate, making the software think "great, so I just need to resample by a factor of 1/100", now if your hardware actually supports say 3 MHz, it silently "adjusts" your request for 4.8 MHz to 3 MHz, and you decimate that by 100, you end up with audio frequencies that are plain wrong, and a audio sample stream that is but 30,000 samples per second, where your

Comment: sound card tries to consume 48,000 per second – choppy audio with strangely high- or low-sounding sound is the result. in short: **check that all parts of your system actually do run at the rate you specify**

Comment: Audio S/R is permanently on 48kHz.  Supported SDR Sampling rates are provided in the SDR software configuration dialogue drop-down menu.

Comment: And changing these rates doesn't help? Your update really indicates that setting a specific sampling rate simply went wrong and you got a different rate.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Check the sample rate configuration in the software
you are using.  Older Apple products used a hardware sample rate of 44.1 ksps, whereas newer Apple products all seem to use a hardware audio sample rate of 48k (or a multiple thereof).

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support this?

Comment: aside from two expert suggesting it's audio sampling rates?

Comment: You're an electrical engineer. I'm a professional recording engineer. I do know a bit about how digital audio hardware works. So again, what is your evidence that "apple products all seem to use a hardware sample rate of 48k"

That aside, if you have any useful suggestions as to why things are getting choppy that would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Mark it's just that I support a lot of people using GNU Radio (which I'm the head maintainer of), and that I do paid support for Ettus (which produce SDR devices), and that's just the number one reason and a sound explanation for what happens: The audio sampling rate your software "produces" is too low (on average) which leads to the exact two phenomena (which, as an recording engineer you'll certainly understand): 1. the audio buffers run empty, so that you get "chunky" audio output, 2. due to the "increased playback speed", the audio is frequency-scaled, ie. sounds higher than it should.

Comment: @Mark so I have experience and a mathematical explanation for the exact phenomenon you see, plus hotpaw2 contributes his Apple experience.

Comment: I'm all ears. Would love to hear what you have to contribute.